# Pass return value from exe to bat and pass it to Process in C#

Tags: c#, c++, batch-file, process

I am working on legacy code where they call a bat file using Process in c#.

```
Process startV6DataExportor = new Process();
startV6DataExportor.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
startV6DataExportor.StartInfo.FileName = strV6BatchPath;
startV6DataExportor.StartInfo.Arguments = strV6batchArgs;
startV6DataExportor.Start();                    
startV6DataExportor.WaitForExit(); 

int v6exitcode = startV6DataExportor.ExitCode;
```

In this bat file, another exe is getting called by passing parameters from bat file.
Like this

```
call %V6_CATSTART_PATH% -run %V6_EXE_NAME% -object "%ROOT_ID% %ROOT_VERSION%"
```

Again in %V6_EXE_NAME% exe, an excel exe is getting called by CreateProcess() in c++
Like this,

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(!CreateProcess(lpctstrBatchPath, // No module name (use command line)
            lpArgs,         // Command line
            NULL,               // Process handle not inheritable
            NULL,               // Thread handle not inheritable
            FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
            0,              // No creation flags
            NULL,               // Use parent's environment block
            NULL,               // Use parent's starting directory 
            &si,                // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            &pi)                // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure 
            )
        {
            printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
            return E_FAIL;
        }
        else
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess,INFINITE);

            DWORD ec;
            GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &ec);       

            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
            unsigned int excelReturnValue = (unsigned int)ec;
            int erv =  static_cast<int>(ec);
        }
}
```

From this excel.exe I get return value 3.
How can I pass this value to the initial c# code?

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @jdweng ExitCode returns nothing in C# process because in previous exe's its not catch properly from excel exe

Comment: Return code is a windows return code and is usually 0 for successful or different number if fails.  Ara you trying to get the exit code or and value that is going to the console (standard output)?

Comment: I need to get the return value from excel.exe and pass it to c# code. By the way what is standard output?

Comment: Standard input in the keyboard and standard output is the console.  With link I provided you can redirect the output from one process to another instead of sending output to the console.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to go through the environment variables

```
NAME

       putenv - change or add an environment variable

SYNOPSIS

       #include <stdlib.h>

       int putenv(char *string);

DESCRIPTION
       The  putenv()  function adds or changes the value of environment
       variables.  The argument string is of the form name=value.  If name does
       not already exist in the environment, then string is added  to  the
       environment.   If name does exist, then the value of name in the
       environment is changed to value.  The string pointed to by string becomes
       part of the environment, so altering the string changes the environment.
```

you push a specific environment variable in your C ++ program and you capture it in your C# program